# Is it right to use "because" here?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to explain a serial inequality: a<=b<=c. Shall I write "The first inequality is because XX and the second inequality is because YY"? Both XX and YY are sentences.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the sentences are fairly short, I see no problem with that construction. For example

> The first inequality is because **grams are less than kilograms** and the
> second inequality is because **kilograms are less than tonnes**.